# In Python on Windows, how can I identify the current process ID using WMI or pywin32?

Tags: python, windows, process, pywin32

On Windows, using the [WMI](https://github.com/tjguk/wmi) library, I can get a list of running Python programs like this

```
c = wmi.WMI()
for process in c.Win32_Process(name="python.exe"):
    print(process.ProcessId, process.Name)
```

An example output is

```
21084 python.exe
10184 python.exe
12320 python.exe
```

How can I find out **which** of these **processes** is the **currently running script**?

I'm trying to use process.Terminate() on all the other Python scripts running,
because sometimes a Python script started by a GUI doesn't close. But I want to
avoid killing the script that does the cleanup - so I need a way of identifing it.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way is to use `os` module to do that:

```
import os, wmi
c = wmi.WMI()
for process in c.Win32_Process(name="python.exe"):
    print(process.ProcessId, process.Name)
print("current processId:", os.getpid())
```

Also you could use `win32api` of `pywin32`:

```
print("current processId:", win32api.GetCurrentProcessId())
```

I also run another script on my PC, this gave me:

```
17944 python.exe
10676 python.exe
current processId: 10676
```